# Configure amount of reserved memory for Linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

I am running Linux on an embedded device with 64MB of physical RAM. Linux prints the following message when it boots:

```
[ 0.000000] Memory: 58944K/65536K available (3072K 
kernel code, 576K rwdata, 832K rodata, 1024K init, 
192K bss, 6592K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

What is the 6592K of 'reserved' memory used for? Is it possible to manually change this value? I can't seem to find any satisfactory explanation for this on the internet.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66299455/5702494) answer suggests the 'reserved' memory is set by `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes`. However, on my system this prints 971 instead of 6592.

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes
971
```

Writing new values to `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes` only changes the amount of `available` memory displayed by the `free` command.

```
# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          59968        7036       48132          40        4800       49616
Swap:             0           0           0
# echo 64 > min_free_kbytes 
# free -k
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          59968        6900       48264          40        4804       52612
Swap:             0           0           0
#
```